# Why does my RigidBody collision fail depending on which entity is moving?

Tags: collision-detection, udk, rigid-body-dynamics

I am working on a UDK project and have a collision problem.

I have a Crate which is a kActor with RigidBody physics and my player who is a Pawn. When my player moves and collides with the crate, the event Bump is called, as expected.

However, when my Crate collides with the Pawn when the Pawn isn't moving, the Bump event is *not* called. In this case, the crate goes through my Pawn without any collision. How can I make this collision case work such that it raises the Bump event?

Comment: Maybe the crate is considered as static collision, so is not expected to move. A flag to turn on somewhere?